# If... elseif, else statement on three lines (or if else on two)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking for how to write an if else statement in two lines in vb.net. I don't mean the ternary operator, although that may work.

For example I want to be to do

`if x = y then matching = true 

elseif x < y then ygreater = true 

else xgreater = true`

I swear I've seen something like this before, possibly using the ":" operator.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter how many lines it is?

Comment: To be honest it really doens't, it's really just for formatting. I'd just like to bring down the linecount on a few basic if else statements and don't really like the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use the : sign to split lines:

```
If x = y Then matching = True: ElseIf x < y Then ygreater = True: Else xgreater = True: End If
```

But why?

Comment: No reason that actually matters, just to make shorter methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the line continuation character `_` to split that single-line statement into three lines.

Comment: These two answers combined are exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but here goes

```
            If x <= y Then If x < y Then ygreater = True Else matching = True Else xgreater = True
```

Proof

```
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim ygreater, xgreater, matching As Boolean
    y = 1
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    For x As Integer = 0 To 2
        Debug.WriteLine("X = {0}   Y = {1}  ", x, y)
        ygreater = False
        xgreater = False
        matching = False
        If x <= y Then If x < y Then ygreater = True Else matching = True Else xgreater = True
        Debug.WriteLine("X > {0}    Y > {1}    Match {2}", xgreater, ygreater, matching)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intInput = x
Select Case intInput
    Case y
        matching = true
    Case IS < y
        ygreater = true
    Case Else
        xgreater = true
End Select
```

In C#.NET you need to use "CASE 1:" (maybe you meant that :)